# how to log all my database changes being done from the application and not only from the django-admin.

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to log all my database changes being done from the application and not only from the django-admin. how can i achieve that ? Currently we can only see the history in django admin for the changes done through the admin interface. do i need to define signals for this?

Answer (score 2):

Django admin uses `LogEntry.objects.log_action` to record those history changes.  There's nothing stopping you from calling that same method in your own code to record changes made elsewhere.

You can use a `pre_save` signal to get the object before committing to the database and then fetch the old values from the database to compare and check for changes.

The formatting of the message can be a plain string, but the admin puts it in a JSON format so it can be translated.  You can look at the source for `construct_change_message` is `django.contrib.admin.utils` to figure out that JSON format if you want to continue using that for the `ManyToManyField`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py, we have to enable logging. Put this code in your settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Django documentation for logging -  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django-db-backends

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of changes possible.

If you are concerned with the structural changes in the database, they are anyways saved in the `migrations` folder inside your app directory.

If you want to log DB changes in terms of entries made in the database, you might find the python package `django-audit-log` useful. You can install it via pip, and once installed, you can add trackers to your models by doing something like this:

```
from audit_log.models.managers import AuditLog

class YourModelName(models.Model):
    #your model definition here
    audit_log = AuditLog()
```

You can find the docs [here](http://django-audit-log.readthedocs.io)

Another alternative is [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) which allows you to do version control for model instances.

Hope this helps!

Comment: my custom requirement is to also log many to many field changes. I don't think both of these do that

Comment: You can actually. Go to this [link](http://django-auditlog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#many-to-many-relationships)